# How to make a POST request to the end point, in views in django for chatterbot?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

i am new to django!

I want to make a chatterbot chatbot in my website, for which i need to make a POST request in views. I have created a model. I am using mysql database for this.

I have visited github and other website and finally got a code, but it doesn't have the POST request

this is my models.py:

```
class Response(models.Model):
statement = models.ForeignKey(
    'Statement',
    related_name='in_response_to',
    on_delete=False
)

response = models.ForeignKey(
    'Statement',
    related_name='+',
    on_delete=False
)

unique_together = (('statement', 'response'),)

occurrence = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

def __str__(self):
    s = self.statement.text if len(self.statement.text) <= 20 else self.statement.text[:17] + '...'
    s += ' => '
    s += self.response.text if len(self.response.text) <= 40 else self.response.text[:37] + '...'
    return s
```

this is where i need to make a POST request in views.py

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    response = Response.objects.all()

    if request.is_ajax():
        input_data = json.loads(request.read().decode('utf-8'))
    else:
        input_data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))

    self.validate(input_data)

    response_data = self.chatterbot.get_response(input_data)

    return JsonResponse(response, response_data, status=200)

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = {
        'detail': 'You should make a POST request to this endpoint.',
        'name': self.chatterbot.name,
        'recent_statements': self._serialize_recent_statements()
    }

    # Return a method not allowed response
    return JsonResponse(data, status=405)
```

Comment: I can see the post method in the view, so where is the problem??

Comment: how should i integrate it in the function get, as it says to make a POST request to this endpoint

Comment: post is different from get method? what do you mean by integrate?? inside get method you want to have post method? confused of what you are trying to do.

Comment: yeah i know post and get are different. the thing is i got this part of the code from github and i did not get why does it say that.. i feel that there is a difference between post and POST.. when i run the code, i am able to see the contents of 'get' on webpage

Comment: no, post and POST are same but in django the method name is written in small, yes in webpage you will see get contents as all request are get when you access a webpage, for POST method you need POSTMAN to give post request

Comment: yeah, then how should i be able to use my chat bot.. i already have a template ready, but when i type anything (for example - 'hi') it does not respond, it just prints what i have typed.

Comment: use ajax and jquery for that, ajax to post data to backend and the returned answer to show in template using jquery

Answer (score 0):

If you're using django rest framework (DRF), i recommend you start by doing [QuickStart](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/quickstart/) and then [Serialization](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/) steps. DRF has a really good documentation and in the Serialization you could find how to make a POST request by defining:

- Models
- Serializers
- Api
- Routers